# Pager.js: How to lazy load bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am trying to figure out how to use Pager.js in conjunction with Knockout.js to lazy-load a page and bind its contents.  I am trying to translate the [demo example](http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/model/lazy_bind_view_model), but I am not familiar with `require.js` and am just getting lost.

I have spent several hours trying to reimplement the system using jQuery's `getJSON` instead of `require` and `define`, but the bindings are failing silently.  I am having two issues:

1. The view model is a JSON array, so I don't know what the array is called
2. The code is not actually doing a `getJSON` request (nothing in the logs). And is failing silently.

Here is the code:

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'history', title: 'History', withOnShow: $root.getHistory }">

var ViewModel = function (data) {
  var self = this;
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

  self.getHistory = function () {
    return function (f) {
      $.getJSON("@{HistoryR}", function (data) {
        viewModel.history = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {});
        f(viewModel.history);
      });
    }
  }          
};

$.getJSON("@{HomeR}", function (data) {
  viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
  pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  pager.start();
});
```

I refactored the code some, to fit in with huocp's answer:

```
  self.getExamHistory = function (f) {
    $.getJSON("@{ExamHistoryR}", function (data) {
      self.history = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {});
      f(self.history);
    });
  }
```

and the getJSON call is getting triggered (and I see the response in my console), but my viewModel.history is still empty.

Comment: Require.js and jQuery's getJSON method are two very different things.  Require.js is a module loader that asynchronously loads a module.  getJSON get's JSON.

Comment: Can the person who voted to close offer a suggestion?

Comment: A suggestion would be to continue on learning and understanding the tech you are trying to use as opposed to asking people to build examples of how apples === oranges

Comment: @PWKad: require.js is loading a module and then apparently using 'define' to define an observable object.  It is also using an obscure style, which is where the problem is happening.  There is also no need to be patronizing.  Some of us are results based people.  Some of us aren't interested in swapping out our infrastructure to fit a framework.

Comment: Also note that the Pager.js documentation does not mention require.js as a dependency, but that they have chosen to use it to inject a model into the code.  I do feel that I have done my due diligence, and have spent several hours trying to decode and reimplement a jQuery version.

Comment: Your question is quite clearly "Can someone translate this code into code that I understand?" which is against the quality standards, so it's not so much patronizing and pointing out why you are unlikely to get help.

Comment: @PWKad: I understand your point now.  Thank you.  That is too bad.  It is difficult to learn pager.js when it uses tools you don't know and will not use in its documentation.  I would be happy to learn pager.js, and have been trying.

Comment: @PWKad: I have substantially restructured the question and added my attempt, with a short list of specific questions.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a wrong wrap of `withOnShow` callback function.

Remove the wrap, you should be fine :-)

```
self.getHistory = function (f) {
  $.getJSON("@{HistoryR}", function (data) {
    self.history = ko.mapping.fromJS(data); // can u try self instead of viewModel
    f(self.history);
  });
};
```

The reason the Pager.js demo page with extra wrap, is that it use `withOnShow: requireVM('invention')`, not `withOnShow: requireVM`. It uses the return value of requireVM function, not the function itself.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm almost there, I think.  The problem I'm seeing now is that the getJSON request is getting triggered (and I see the response object in my javascript console), but my viewModel.history is still null. :(

Comment: didnot check that. it's `viewModel.history = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);`, I think `fromJS` did not take empty object as options, instead it thinks that is a viewModel to be updated. Updated answer.

Comment: forget about my explanation, I just tested in console, it makes no difference with/without second empty param.

Comment: Yes, thank you for that.  That was a problem as well, and I had fixed it.  But I has also broken the code by setting the observable as 'history' instead of $root.history.  Do you know off hand how to set the binding so that it's "local" to the pager.js page?  (But, also, thank you thank you thank you!  You have saved me. :)

Comment: You can try http://pagerjs.com/demo/#!/model/change_binding_context, but I think you will have trouble if `history` is an array. Did you try knockout 3.2.0-beta with component? http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2014/06/11/architecting-large-single-page-applications-with-knockout-js/ I stopped from using Pager.js because of this.